# 'There's nothing to match tea as a refreshing drink.'

Tags: comparative-constructions, infinitive-clauses

I'm doing a grammar exercise and I have to complete the sentence underneath

> A cup of tea is the most refreshing drink of all. 
>   There's.................as a refreshing drink.

The given word is  *'match'*

The answer key says *'There's nothing to match tea as a refreshing drink.'*

Can somebody explain this structure, it looks weird to me, especially the preposition *'as'* used with *'match'*

Comment: ... or *"there's nothing that matches tea ..."* So there's at least two reasonable answers.

Answer (score 1):

The preposition '*as*' is paired with '*tea*', and not with '*match*'.  The structure is

> There is nothing to match {what?}
>   .. here {what?} = "tea as a refreshing drink".

"*Tea as a refreshing drink*" is an objective clause.

The meaning is that if we look at *tea* considering only its quality of being *a refreshing drink*, then there is nothing that *matches* it (among other refreshing drinks).